# Replacing string literals in c# using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string-literals

I am trying to replace all string literals in a string, with placeholders. For example if I have the following string:

> string s1 = "foo"; string s2 = "bar"; string s3 = "baz";

I would like to replace this with:

> string s1 = #0#; string s2 = #1#; string s2 = #2#;

and also retain the replaced string literals {"foo","bar", "baz"} in a data structure for later use.

I can do this through brute force ugly coding. However, I am wondering whether there is a nice way of doing this using regular expressions?

My attempt was:

```
MatchCollection textConstants = Regex.Matches(text, "\".*\"");
for (int i=0; i < textConstants.Count; i++)
{
    text=text.Replace(textConstants[i].Value, "#" + i + "#");
}'
```

This does not seem very nice

Comment: Have you made an attempt at using regular expressions? If you show effort in solving the problem and explain where you got stuck, people can help you much more than just spoon-feeding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

And now you have two problems:

```
var s = "string s1 = \"foo\"; string s2 = \"bar\"; string s3 = \"baz\";";

var list = new List<string>();

var result = Regex.Replace(s, "\".*?\"", m => { list.Add(m.Value); 
                                                return "#" + (list.Count - 1) + "#"; });
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the answer I was hoping for

Comment: [It is not correct](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22.*%3f%22&i=string+s1+%3d+%22%5c%22foo%5c%22%22%3b) because string literals may contain escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this msdn article.  It's a good starting point on how to use regular expressions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks.This is helpful